# Prove the existence of inverse of matrix $A$ if $A$ satisfies a polynomial equation

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I encounter this strange problem in a textbook. Let $A$ be a square matrix of dimensions $n$ by $n$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^K a_kA^k=0.
$$
Show that the inverse of $A$ exists.
This result is natural if $A$ is a scalar but not clear if $A$ is a matrix.

Could anyone give me an idea how to go about this problem? Thank you.

Comment: The claim is only true if $a_0\ne 0$.

Comment: If $a_0 \ne 0$, then $A^0 = -\frac 1{a_0} \sum_{k=1}^{K}a_kA^k$.

Comment: Hint: Try to find a formula for $A^{-1}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

From $0=a_0 I + \sum_{k=1}^K a_k A^k,$ it immediately follows that
$$
I=-\frac{1}{a_0}\sum_{k=1}^K a_kA^k.
$$
By definition, an inverse is a matrix $B$ such that $AB=BA=I$.